# Why index is not used for tstarange field when function call is made?

Tags: postgresql

For this case when `timestamp` is constant index is used:

```
explain analyse select * from order_bt where '2019-03-01'::timestamptz <@ sys_period;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN             
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using order_id_sys_period_app_period_excl on order_bt  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1
   Index Cond: ('2019-03-01 00:00:00+02'::timestamp with time zone <@ sys_period)
 Planning time: 0.185 ms
 Execution time: 0.085 ms
(4 rows)
```

but when I make call to function which returns `timestamp` index is not used:

```
explain analyse select * from order_bt where sys_time() <@ sys_period;
                                                 QUERY PLAN                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on order_bt  (cost=0.00..1050.78 rows=19 width=136) (actual time=0.099..36.676 r
   Filter: (sys_time() <@ sys_period)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 927
 Planning time: 0.142 ms
 Execution time: 37.065 ms
(5 rows)
```

what is the problem with function call for second query?
How explain PG to use index?

Answer (score 0):

[Probably found](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/xfunc-volatility.html):

> A STABLE function cannot modify the database and is guaranteed to return the same results given the same arguments for all rows within a single statement. This category allows the optimizer to optimize multiple calls of the function to a single call. In particular, it is safe to use an expression containing such a function in an index scan condition. (Since an index scan will evaluate the comparison value only once, not once at each row, **it is not valid to use a VOLATILE function in an index scan condition.**)

My function was `volatile`